# Invalid snowflake.topic2table.map

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone tell me why my **snowflake.topic2table.map** value is being reported as invalid by my Snowflake Sink Connector?  The KAFKA_TEST
 database has been created in Snowflake and I am ok to let the sink connector create the table for me.  When I remove the **snowflake.topic2table.map** setting from the configuration, it works ok ... but I'd like to control the name of the table being created.  I am using Confluent 5.3.1 and Snowflake Connector 0.50.

`[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Invalid snowflake.topic2table.map config format: snowflake.topic2table.map (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.Utils:417)`

My sink config:

```
{                                                                                        
  "name" : "mySnowflakeSink",
  "config":{
    "connector.class" : "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "2",
    "topics" : "sink-sample-data",
    "snowflake.topic2table.map" : "sink-sample-data:sampledata",
    "buffer.count.records" : "5",
    "snowflake.url.name" : "xxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "snowflake.user.name" : "JPARDI",
    "snowflake.private.key" : "yyyyyyy",
    "snowflake.private.key.passphrase" : "zzzzzzz",
    "snowflake.database.name" : "KAFKA_TEST",
    "snowflake.schema.name" : "PUBLIC",
    "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter" : "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter"
  }                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that it's a known issue in the Snowflake connector fixed 5 days ago by [this commit](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/commit/8a6d2a207ff5331a447f408a62393874e7f20460), and not released yet.

The problem was that instead of the passing the configuration value that you specified, the code parsed the name of the property itself: `snowflake.topic2table.map`.